# Selenium XPath Query - FindElement After Text

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I am trying to get a link in a website which changes name on a daily basis. The structure is similar to this (but with many more levels):

```html
<li>
   <div class = "contentPlaceHolder1">
      <div class="content">
         <p>
            <strong>'Today's File Here:<strong>
         </p>
      </div>
   </div>
</li>
<li>...<li>
<li>...<li>
<li>...<li>
<li>
  <div class = "contentPlaceHolder1">
      <div class="content">
         <div class="DocLink">
            <li>
               <a href = "http://changingURL" class="txtLnk">Download</a>
            </li>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</li>
<li>...<li>

etc...
```

If I find the text (which will remain constant) which is immediately above it in the page by using

```
IWebElement foundTextElement = chrome.FindElement(By.XPath("//p/strong['Today's File Here:']"));
```

How can I find the next link in the page by using XPath (or alternative solution)? I am unsure of how to search for the next element after this.

If I use

```
IWebElement link = chrome.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@class='txtLnk'"));
```

then this finds the first link in the page. I only want the first occurance of it after 'foundTextElement'

I have had it working by navigating up the tree to the parent above `<li>`, and finding the 4th sibling using `By.XPath("following-sibling::*[4]/div/div/div/li/a[@class='txtLnk']")` but that seems a little precarious to me.

I could parse the HTML until it finds the next occurrence in the html, but was wondering whether there is a more clever way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this xpath. It's complicated, as we don't see the rest of the page to optimize it

```
//li[preceding-sibling::li[.//*[contains(text(),'File Here')]]][.//a[contains(@class,'txtLnk')]][1]
```

it searches first `li` which has inside `a` tag with `txtLnk` class and it is first found followed after `li` element with text containing `File Here`

Comment: Thanks Vitaliy. Yes - this it is complicated but works a treat. It takes the element to the immediate parent <li>, but that is fine - I can have a play to get it to go to the child <a>. Temporarily, I'm finding the child of that using IWebElement link2 = link.FindElement(By.XPath(".//a['Download']"));. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
By.XPath("//a[@class='txtLnk'")
```

Is a very generic selector, there might be other elements on the page using the same class

You can find this using a CssSelector, try this:

```
IWebElement aElement = chrome.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.contentPlaceHolder1 div.content div.DocLink li a"));
```

Then you can get the href using:

```
string link = aElement.getAttribute("href") ;
```

Comment: Hi Moe. Thanks for your answer. Would using the CssSelector have the same problem though? If there are other elements higher up / further down the page with the same Css?